# How to create class in a custom CSS file by JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to create a CSS class at runtime using JavaScript and write in a custom CSS file.

Now I wrote the code (see below) and created my class but I don't know how to create it in my CSS file.

```js
var sheet = document.createElement('style')
    sheet.innerHTML = ".context-menu-icon-case1:before{content: url(progressbar.png);}";
    document.body.appendChild(sheet);
```

It creates the CSS class in my current page but I want to create it in a custom css file.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're saying. Do you mean you want to write it out to a CSS file on the server?

Comment: Are you trying to write a `.css` file to local filesystem?

Comment: @guest271314 no my css file befor created I wnat only append some class to it as runtime by java script

Comment: First you say that you want to create it in a custom CSS file (sounds like write-to-file which cannot be done), than you say you want to append on runtime some class to an element... which is not true since you actually want to assign a **style** (to some `:before` element). Please try to be more precise when asking questions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can request the existing `.css` file using `XMLHttpRequest()` or `fetch()` instead of loading the file at `html`, append the new style rule to the `.css` file at `XMLHttpRequest.responseText` or `response.text()`, or using `FileReader`.

Create a `Blob` or `File` object, or encoded text representation of new `css` text appended to existing file, create a `<link>` element with `rel` attribute set to `stylesheet`, `href` attribute to an `objectURL`, `data URI` or encoded text of the created file, append the `link` element to `document.head`.

```
<head>
  <script>
    var cssupdate = `.context-menu-icon-case1:before {
                       content: url(progressbar.png);
                    }`;
    var cssfile = "style.css";
    fetch(cssfile)
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(currentcss => {
      var css = currentcss + "\n" + `${cssupdate}`;
      var link = document.createElement("link");
      link.rel = "stylesheet";
      link.type = "text/css";
      link.href = "data:text/css," + encodeURIComponent(css); 
      document.querySelector("head").appendChild(link);
    });
  </script>
</head>
```

plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/Gh0qR4CcQPROXCldX9OC?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

You can't. I am sorry. Good news is you don't need to. Inserting CSS through Javascript is the same as reading from a css file.

Answer (score -1):

You can just write a css class in css file,  and then apply the css class on runtime by javascript, like this:

```
html file:
<div id="test"></div>

css file:
.context-menu-icon-case1: {
  color: xxx,
  width: xxx
}

javascript file:
var ele = document.getElementById("test");
ele.className += "context-menu-icon-case1";
```

Comment: `: {` and comma-separated properties in CSS? Also using `className +=` you should provide firstly a space character, or simply use `classList.add`